# What canon level will the 7th Star Wars movie be?

Tags: star-wars, canon

[The Holocron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon#The_Holocron) defines different canon level for the Star Wars Universe.

In the end of the Wikipedia paragraph :

> *Leland Chee, December 6th, 2006:* "Anything not in the current version of the films is irrelevant to Film only continuity."
>
> This statement confirms the existence of two separate continuities, the "film only" continuity maintained and followed by George Lucas himself, and the "films + EU" continuity that is used for licensed products; G-Canon, and Star Wars Canon.

So... since, as I understood, Lucas will only be a consultant on the 7th movie, will it be considered G-Canon ?

Comment: do we add a new level of D-canon above G-canon?

Comment: This question is officially considered off-topic so far, based on [this Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/are-questions-related-to-d-canon-in-star-wars-welcome-at-the-moment)

Comment: "So, no, no questions on this... until the new canon rules actually are implemented." - from that meta

Comment: That quote has a number of problems though: 1) there are more than two continuties/canon levels. 2) If we follow that quote to the letter, you can argue that ESB and RotJ are not G-Canon as he did not write the scripts or direct the films. He was a producer - just like he will be with the new films. 3) The quote is just simply outdated now. The reigns have been handed over.

Comment: @phantom42 Why is the quote outdated ? The Holocron and the different canon levels still exist, don't they ?

Comment: @Kalissar It's outdated because at the time, Lucas held all rights to Star Wars. No one could supersede him in any way. That's no longer true. The Holocron still exists, but there are more than 2 levels of canon (the link you provided even lists them) - and have been for a number of years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see what Lucas has to do with the question at all. He sold the rights so technically he has nil to say anymore how Star Wars develops in the future.
The **owner** of the Star Wars right says what is canon and what is not. And that is now **Disney**.

He is consulting and they are apparently listening to him. He also made sure that there are still good people at Lucasfilm to carry on his legacy. But in the end **Disney** is the new owner of the rights and they can pretty much do as they please. I doubt that Lucas has any serious pull when it comes to it.

So this and the future movies should be what is currently defined as G-Canon and they should supersede anything except the other movies.

Comment: yup, it will be a Disney cannon. Buffy the vampire slayer meets R2D2?

Comment: @jwenting The Vampires Strike Back?...I sure hope not.

Comment: Sith Mickey and princess Miney?

Comment: @Sebastian_H  - will the vampires sparkle and warble?

Comment: @DVK Not only do they sparkle, they are all clones of the same guy...a clone army, so to speak. Ingenious, if I may say so.

Comment: @Sebastian_H - of all the franchises, in all the studios, you had to waltz into that one :(

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the role Lucas is taking is the same as (or at least reasonably similar to) his role with Episodes 5 and 6 - the story originates with him, he doesn't write the script or direct, but he does have final say on what does or doesn't go in.  So based on that I'd expect that it would have the same level of canon as Episodes 5 and 6.